# Replace any Special/Foreign Characters from a "Url Friendly" String

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I need to remove any special characters from a String, replace spaces to hifens and then use it as a URL Friendly string, so i came to this function:

```
function removeCharacters($string){

$a = array(' ','À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','Æ','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë','Ì','Í','Î','Ï','Ð','Ñ','Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö','Ø','Ù','Ú','Û','Ü','Ý','ß','à','á','â','ã','ä','å','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ñ','ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ø','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','ÿ','Ā','ā','Ă','ă','Ą','ą','Ć','ć','Ĉ','ĉ','Ċ','ċ','Č','č','Ď','ď','Đ','đ','Ē','ē','Ĕ','ĕ','Ė','ė','Ę','ę','Ě','ě','Ĝ','ĝ','Ğ','ğ','Ġ','ġ','Ģ','ģ','Ĥ','ĥ','Ħ','ħ','Ĩ','ĩ','Ī','ī','Ĭ','ĭ','Į','į','İ','ı','Ĳ','ĳ','Ĵ','ĵ','Ķ','ķ','Ĺ','ĺ','Ļ','ļ','Ľ','ľ','Ŀ','ŀ','Ł','ł','Ń','ń','Ņ','ņ','Ň','ň','ŉ','Ō','ō','Ŏ','ŏ','Ő','ő','Œ','œ','Ŕ','ŕ','Ŗ','ŗ','Ř','ř','Ś','ś','Ŝ','ŝ','Ş','ş','Š','š','Ţ','ţ','Ť','ť','Ŧ','ŧ','Ũ','ũ','Ū','ū','Ŭ','ŭ','Ů','ů','Ű','ű','Ų','ų','Ŵ','ŵ','Ŷ','ŷ','Ÿ','Ź','ź','Ż','ż','Ž','ž','ſ','ƒ','Ơ','ơ','Ư','ư','Ǎ','ǎ','Ǐ','ǐ','Ǒ','ǒ','Ǔ','ǔ','Ǖ','ǖ','Ǘ','ǘ','Ǚ','ǚ','Ǜ','ǜ','Ǻ','ǻ','Ǽ','ǽ','Ǿ','ǿ');
$b = array('-','A','A','A','A','A','A','AE','C','E','E','E','E','I','I','I','I','D','N','O','O','O','O','O','O','U','U','U','U','Y','s','a','a','a','a','a','a','ae','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','n','o','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y','A','a','A','a','A','a','C','c','C','c','C','c','C','c','D','d','D','d','E','e','E','e','E','e','E','e','E','e','G','g','G','g','G','g','G','g','H','h','H','h','I','i','I','i','I','i','I','i','I','i','IJ','ij','J','j','K','k','L','l','L','l','L','l','L','l','l','l','N','n','N','n','N','n','n','O','o','O','o','O','o','OE','oe','R','r','R','r','R','r','S','s','S','s','S','s','S','s','T','t','T','t','T','t','U','u','U','u','U','u','U','u','U','u','U','u','W','w','Y','y','Y','Z','z','Z','z','Z','z','s','f','O','o','U','u','A','a','I','i','O','o','U','u','U','u','U','u','U','u','U','u','A','a','AE','ae','O','o');

return str_replace($a,$b,$string);

}
```

It works ok but when i use some foreign characters everything got messed up. For example:

```
//Opening on миэт çǿůитÐфщи ђэιιø Ĵąẵ
```

The output keep the Special Characters, I tried to do an extra filter using:

```
$string = str_replace($a,$b,$string);
return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", "", $string);
```

On the end of my function but then it Outputs:

```
//Opening-on-1084108011011090-c51136710801090D109210971080-11061101953953o-3082617861
```

I need to keep the String Numbers but I don't want any other Characters expect Regular Letters (A-Za-z) and numbers (0-9).

I already tried inconv, URLify and many others functions but can't do it right...

Is this possible ? How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gives you a url friendly string

```
public function getUrlFriendlyString($string)
{
    $string = mb_strtolower($string);
    $string = str_replace(array('ä','ö','ß','ü'), array('ae','oe','ss','ue'), $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z ]#', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#\s\s+#', ' ', $string);
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);

    return $string;
}
```

example input

`Replace any Special/Foreign Characters from a “Url Friendly” String`

output

`replace-any-specialforeign-characters-from-a-url-friendly-string`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the error still the same as my code... if I use the Characters on my question the output is //opening-on-1084108011011090-51136710801090109210971080-11061101953953-3082617861

Comment: maybe something is wrong with your document encoding on ``utf8`` the response with your example string gives me ``opening-on`` ?

Comment: look here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/858b21133cf20d25ead4cd19f7d77a299d50735e

Comment: You're right, my page charset is ISO-8859-1, but utf8_encode($_POST['field']) should not fix this ?

Comment: hard to say but with my experience i can say that if you need to use ``utf8_encode`` to hack some values in the right place, you have still multiple file charsets and are not complete on ``utf8``

Comment: Man, this is weird, I always thought that utf8_encode could handle with this strings. Now i'm trying to understand why doesn't work as expected. Anyway, thanks for your help, it saved me a lot of time.